# XMl parsing condtions

Tags: iphone

HI, all, i am not sure how to write if and else condition in order to parse xml.
this is how my returned xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a><a1>A</a1></a>
<b><b1>B</b1></b>
<c><c1>C</c1></c>
<d><d1>D</d1></d>
<e><e1>E</e1></e>
<f><f1>F</f1></f>
<g><g1>G</g1></g>
```

i tried various condition, but i am not able to properly navigate through each node.

How should i write if / else condition in

```
"-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
//if and else condition here

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b"]) {

 }
…………
}"
```

and "-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{}"

and finally in here

```
"-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
//if else condition here
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b"]) {

 }

……
}
"
```

i need to pass the returned values from xml like, A,B,C  to NSSTring for further programming..but i am not even able to parse it.

thanks 
Suggestions are always appreciated

Comment: Is that the actual xml?  The x1 tags should terminate before x.

Comment: +1 @abitobvious. Nothing wrong with your if/elses by the way thats what you're supposed to do.

Comment: thank all for replying..i edited my demo xml above,  ..i just need to get the values A,B,C and pass it to some string.

Comment: hi, i m only able to navigate through first node only, how can i go navgiate through each node?. thank

Answer (score 1):

As always, [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html) on `NSXMLParser` is excellent. What you probably want to do is implement the delegate method `parser:foundCharacters:` and accumulate the text inside your nodes (i.e., with an `NSMutableString`). `didStartElement:` and `didEndElement:` will tell you when you enter and exit elements, as you already know. From there it's just a matter of storing the text in a suitable data structure for further processing.

Comment: thanks warrenm, i used the same thing in my code....i m just confused about the if/else condition in my situation. i am not able to properly navigate through each node of xml, can u plz let me knw, how should i write if/else to naviagte through each node.thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but XML documents are naturally represented as tree structures. You could use an NSMutableArray like a stack to keep track of your current position in the tree ("a"->"a1"->text node). Is that what you mean by "navigate"?